# Simple PHP IDE in PHP

Tags: open-source, php, ide

I need a simple IDE, which can edit local files (files in the folder of the IDE), FTP function / plugin available, written in PHP + HTML, CSS and JS only, and is open source.

What are the suggestions except *codiad* (it is continuously causing "CPU Limit Exceeded")?

Comment: you should explain why is codiad not suited for you, may give clues as to what yo actually recommend

Comment: I guess I just want to find another one... I'll explain in the question though.

Comment: Why do you care that it is written in PHP? Do you really expect to extend it? That requirement is cutting out some good stuff, like NetBeans

Comment: I need it to be hosted online... I can't use an offline one.

Comment: Thus there is too many local ones... netbean, phpstorm, simple search would do, but not one in PHP.

Comment: Do you want an IDE which is written in PHP, or written to develop PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found exactly what your looking for, IceCoder

**[ICEcoder](https://icecoder.net/)** (Open Source, $10 for v5.x)

> ICEcoder is an open-source browser code editor, which provides a
>   modern approach to building websites. By allowing you to code directly
>   within the web browser, online or offline, it means you only need one
>   program (your browser) to develop sites, plus can test on actual web
>   servers. After development, you can also maintain the website easily,
>   all of which make for speedy and smart development.

Check out ICEcoder's features here: https://icecoder.net/features

[image: ICEcoder's User Interface]